# unable to download file

Tags: magento2.4.3, downloader

looked a lot of solution similar to this

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory




 $fileName = 'test.pdf';
$this->fileFactory->create(
                $fileName,
                [
                    'type' => 'filename',
                    'value' => 'abc/'.$fileName
                ],
                DirectoryList::MEDIA , //basedir
                'application/zip',
            );
```

but instead of file download I get  sort of this response in the network tab, **this is an ajax call to the controller**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below for return as response may it helps you

```
   $resultJsonArray = $yourFile;
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $resultJson->setData($resultJsonArray);
    return $resultJson;
```

Comment: nope still same